# Removing the empty data spaces and retaining the uniform bar width in grouped bar chart. Using facet grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

Following is the code I am using to plot a grouped bar chart:
I am able to retain the uniform bar width but unable to remove the empty spaces of missing data if I am using

```
geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(preserve = "single"),na.rm = TRUE,width = 0.9).
```

And if I am not using the above command I am not able to retain the bar width although I am able to remove empty spaces.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("Documents/Analysis.xlsx")

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Cell_type, y = Percentage_of_cell, fill = Sample_id, na.rm = TRUE),
       position = position_dodge(preserve = "single", padding = 0)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"), na.rm = TRUE, width = 0.9)+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgoldenrod3","darkolivegreen"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(color="black", angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 12, face = "bold"), 
        axis.title.y = element_text( size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = .5, vjust = .5, face = "bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  labs(fill="") + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab("% of Cell_type\n") + 
  facet_grid(~Cell_type), 
             scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1.5,1.2),"cm"))+ 
  theme(strip.text = element_text(colour = 'black', face="bold", size=11))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Here is df:

```
Sample_id Cell_type Percentage_of_cell   
Sample1 Cell1   4.701222662  
Sample2 Cell1   0.829875519  
Sample2 Cell2   5.526216522  
Sample1 Cell3   1.980368521  
Sample2 Cell3   20.50169747  
Sample1 Cell4   22.75701739  
Sample2 Cell4   21.3504338  
Sample1 Cell5   15.00774927  
Sample2 Cell5   9.430403621  
Sample1 Cell6   7.465128293  
Sample1 Cell7   0.602720854  
Sample2 Cell7   1.772915881  
Sample1 Cell8   44.07611503  
Sample2 Cell8   40.58845719  
Sample1 Unassigned  3.409677975
```

I am new to R, please help in pointing out where I am going wrong or if there is any other solution to this problem.

Comment: if you edit `df` in this way: `tidyr::complete(df, Sample_id, tidyr::nesting(Cell_type), fill = list(Percentage_of_cell = 0)) `, do you get what you expected? [the problem was for Cell 2, right?]

Comment: I tried the same. However it is not working for me, the problem is with Cell2, Cell6, and Unassigned where I have data from one of the sample only.

Comment: then I don't understand your expected result. Do you want the column in the center when it's alone?

Comment: Yes, I want to bar in the center of Cell2, Cell6 facets rather than in Sample1 and Sample2 space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

NOTE that:

- `x` in `aes` is now `Sampl_id`
- `position_dodge` has been removed
- `geom_col` is less wordy than `geom_bar` if you need `stat=identity`
- `theme`s and `lab`s are all together now
- `scales` and `space` in `facet_grid` now work as expected

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Sample_id, y = Percentage_of_cell, fill = Sample_id)) +
 geom_col(width = 0.9) +
 facet_grid(cols = vars(Cell_type), 
            labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 16,multi_line = TRUE), 
            scales="free", space = "free") +
 labs(x = "", y = "% of Cell_type\n", fill = "") +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgoldenrod3", "darkolivegreen")) +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(), 
       axis.text.y  = element_text(color = "black", angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 12, face = "bold"), 
       axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
       legend.text  = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
       axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
       plot.margin  = unit(c(1,1,1.5,1.2),"cm"),
       strip.text   = element_text(colour = 'black', face = "bold", size = 11),
       legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]